# If statement evaluating to false even when the condition is true

Tags: c++, c++11

My program skips over the if statement `counter==4` even if counter is 4. When I try to debug, it will never check this if statement, it completely skips it every time.

```
    int num;
    int counter = 1;
    while (file >> num) {
        if (counter == 1) {
            //code
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            //code
        }

        if (counter == 2) {
            //code
        }

        if (counter == 4) {   //completely skips this if
            counter == 1;
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: ok i think visual studio was just being weird. i deleted the statement and rewrote it and it worked. this is by far the weirdest error i have encountered lol.

Comment: You wrote `counter == 1` in stead of `counter = 1` which compares `counter` to 1 and ignores the result rather then assigning 1 to `counter`. Since the line is useless and does nothing it might get optimized away which would explain the debugger skipping it.

Comment: Btw the likely reason for skipping the if-statement is because the if-statement got optimized out of your program (because the optimizer correctly determined that it would not change the behavior of your program if the if-statement was removed)

Comment: Glad it worked! Please close/delete the question now. None of the content explains the behaviour you described which is thus not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You have this piece:

```
    if (counter == 4) {   //completely skips this if
        counter == 1;
    }
```

It is not skipped (as far as can be seen from the code you posted). It just doesn't do anything. You *compare* `counter` to 1, and then throw away the resulting boolean value.

To fix, switch to assignment, use `counter = 1`.

Your compiler should have warned you about "code has no effect". Turn on warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang*, `/W3` or `/W4` for Visual Studio are good), and *fix them*.